# Java Get Substring Between Two Indexes

Tags: java, string

For example I have this string: `Hello, world!` and I want to get `Hello` by using indexes. Is there a function like

```java
package com.example;

import static java.lang.String.getStringBetweenIndex;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello, world!";

        System.out.println(hello.getStringBetweenIndex(0, 5));
    }
}
```

that gives output `Hello`?

Comment: You titled and tagged this question `substring`, have you tried that?

Comment: I never knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex);` method for that. Try;

```java
package com.example;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello, world!";

        System.out.println(hello.substring(0, 5));
    }
}
```

Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex. Examples:

- `"hamburger".substring(4, 8)` returns "urge"
- `"smiles".substring(1, 5)` returns "mile"

Parameters:

- `beginIndex` - the beginning index, inclusive.
- `endIndex` - the ending index, exclusive.

Returns:

the specified substring.

Throws:

- IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Source:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)

Comment: Nice, a good answer with documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String substring​(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.
Examples:

- `"hamburger".substring(4, 8)` returns "urge"
- `"smiles".substring(1, 5)` returns "mile"

Parameters:

- `beginIndex` - the beginning index, inclusive.
- `endIndex` - the ending index, exclusive.

Returns:

- the specified substring.

Throws:

- IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)

Comment: Thank you! It really helps.